# Myhill–Nerode equivalence classes of $\{0^n1^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: finite-automata

I am told to find the equivalence classes of the Myhill–Nerode relation of the language $\{0^n1^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. For one, I know it has an infinite number of equivalence classes given that it's a non-regular language. Im not sure how to find all the equivalence classes and show how I got those equivalence classes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to think of this question. The equivalence relation is determined by which extensions of the current word belong to the language. There are three cases:

- The current word is not a prefix of any word in the language. This happens if either the word is not in $0^*1^*$ at all, or if it is of the form $0^n1^m$ but $m > n$.
- There is a unique extension of the current word which is in the language. This happens if the word is of the form $0^n1^m$ with $m \neq 0$ (and, to exclude the case above, $m \leq n$).
- There are multiple extensions of the current word which are in the language. This happens for words in $0^*$.

Let us now get into more detail:

- If $w = 0^n$, then we can extend $w$ to a word in the language by adding $0^m 1^{n+m}$ for arbitrary $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that this set of extensions is different for every $n$.
- If $w = 0^n1^m$ where $0 < m \leq n$ then there is a unique way to extend $w$ to a word in the language, namely by adding $1^{n-m}$.
- Otherwise, $w$ cannot be extended to a word in the language.

Accordingly, the equivalence classes are:

- $\{0^n\}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- $\{0^{n+m} 1^m : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- Everything else.

Comment: Understood...thank you.